# htacces rewrite rule trailing slash and one page as sub page of other page

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Hello friends I have search lot but not found solution for my problem about rewriting url.

I have a website having pages a.html and page b.html and want them to have links like this
mywebsite.com/a/ instead of mywebsite.com/a.html

and
mywebsite.com/a/b/ instead of mywebsite.com/b.html

both of these pages are present in root directory. so how can i use apache rewrite rule in htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+([^\/]+)?(?:index)?(a)\.html[\s?/] [NC]
RewriteRule ^a\.html$ /%1%2 [R=302,L,NE]
RewriteRule ^a/$ /a.html [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+([^\/]+)?(?:index)?(b)\.html[\s?/] [NC]
RewriteRule ^b\.html$ /a/%1%2/ [R=302,L,NE]
RewriteRule ^a/b/$ /b.html [L]
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(b)\/?$
RewriteRule ^ /a/%1/ [R=302,L,NE]
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/a/b)$
RewriteRule ^  %1/ [R=302,L,NE]
```

So , the code above will match `/a.html , /a or /a/` then change it to `/a/` externally and redirect it to `/a.html` internally.

Also match  `/b.html ,/b or /b/` then change it to `/a/b/` externally and redirect it to `/b.html` internally .

**Note:** clear browser cache and test it , if it is Ok , change any `302` to `301` to get permanent redirection.